# Multiply and IF function

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, multiplication

I am trying to write a formula that if c7 is over 90 the number in that column multiplies by 4, If the number is over 100 it should multiply by 6. I have this formula and it is not multiplying by 6 when over 100. What am I doing wrong? HELP!!   =C7*IF(C7>90,4,IF(C7>100,6,0))

Tried the above formula and if half works.

Comment: You should tag this with excel or whatever language you use?

Comment: You have them in the wrong order.  If C7 > 100, then it will already have been handled  in the C7 > 90 path.  `=C7*IF(C7>100,4,IF(C7>90,4,0))`.

Comment: Consider using the `ifs` statement (untested)  `=ifs(c7 <= 90, 0, c7 <= 100, 4 * c7, true, 6 * c7)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using formula for excel here.
Here is the solution `=IF(C7>100,C7*6,IF(C7>90,C7*4,0))`

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
= C7 * IF(C7 > 90, 4, IF(C7 > 100, 6, 0))
```

will *not* multiply by 6 if it's over a hundred because the *first* check is if it's over 90.

Since anything over a hundred is also over 90, it will be caught by that first check and therefore be multiplied by four.

So, reversing the conditions (and I prefer a "direct connection" to the result so I've put the full expressions inside the `if`), you would use something like:

```
= if(c7 > 100, c7 * 6, if(c7 > 90, c7 * 4, 0))
```

And you should be aware that you're likely to get zero for values not greater than 90. I suspect the correct thing to do in that case would be to leave it alone. For that, you would change that final `0` to be a `1`.

And, as suggested in a comment, it may be better to use `ifs` in this case so as to avoid unnecessary nesting. There's only two levels for your case but you'll be glad the `ifs` exists when that number increases:

```
= IFS(c7 > 100, c7 * 6, c7 > 90, c7 * 4, true, 0) ' c7 at end to multiply by one
```